# $ in computer object SAMAccountName

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

In active directory all machine accounts '$' sign in end of the Sam Account Name.
for ex 'samAccountName = client-1$'

is there any reason behind it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of where you're seeing this?

Comment: @ArrowRoot i have added screenshot.please refer this

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign indicates that the computer account has been joined to the domain and has authenticated (logged on). A computer account that has been created but has not logged on will not have the dollar sign appended to the samAccountName.

Comment: but not logged on machines also have $ sign.